Как подобрать слои для языковой модели на PyTorch?
Всех приветствую, впервые использую StackOverflow, так как столкнулся с одной проблемой. Я создаю нейросеть, которая основываясь на написанном в сообщении будет угадывать слова, которыми можно ответить. Для обучения я взял переписку из Telegram в формате Json. Всю её перевёл в лист из строк и сделал кастомный датасет, в котором каждый ввод представляет собой тензор размерностью с словарь из всех слов в переписке, чтобы каждый индекс отвечал за частоту употребления отдельно взятого слова. Я хочу, чтобы я давал на входе такой Bag of words в формате int и получал точно такой же на выходе, чтобы перевести обратно в слова. Однако я вроде разобрался, модель даже запускается, всё вроде работает, но что после обучения, что до она подбирает веса и выдаёт один и тот же вывод, вне зависимости от ввода. Ранее пытался использовать эмбеддинговые слои, но нейронка вообще превращала тензор в кашу. Можете мне подсказать какие лучше использовать слои и как организовать цикл обучения ?
class Jester(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_tensor_size, vocab_size, embedding_dim,hidden_dim ):
        super(Jester, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_dim,hidden_size=hidden_dim,num_layers=3,)

        self.out_linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim,input_tensor_size)


        #self.output_layer = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x)
        out_embedded = self.embedding(x)
        print (out_embedded.shape)
        out,hidden = self.lstm(out_embedded)
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.out_linear(out)
        out = torch.round(out)
        print(out.shape)
        return out , hidden

def train(dataloader, model, optimizer,criterion):
    print("[System] Start training loops")
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0

    for epoch in range(1):
        print(f"[Training] Epoch - {epoch}")
        for x,y in tqdm(dataloader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            prediction = model(x)
            loss = criterion(prediction,y.float())

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()

        #print(prediction)
        print(f"[Training] Epoch - {epoch} || Loss is {running_loss/len(dataloader)}")

